# ImageResizer and S3Reader2: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, imageresizer

I'm upgrading a website to a .NET website using MVC5 using ImageResizer with the images stored on AWS S3. The images stored on S3 are fine, have public read access and load without a problem when calling the S3 URL.

When I use the ImageResizer plugin S3Reader2 I get the following error on most of my images: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 26."

You can find the ImageResizer Diagnostics here: [Diagnostics](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35713bd3736a932840fa)

You can find the stack trace here: [Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/412ca79913f5bb4f46d6)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide links to both failing and non-failing blobs? I've [filed an associated issue on AWSSDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/202), since this result isn't correct regardless of what the blob metadata contains.

Comment: I've replied on the GitHub issue. Can you provide a presigned url for one of the problematic objects so we can examine the headers associated with it?

Comment: @NathanaelJones Can't add links to main question do to reputation limit. S3: http://media.fotoapparatuur.nl/IG/85070.jpg
ImageResizer not OK: http://test.fotoapparatuur.nl:42424/s3/media.fotoapparatuur.nl/IG/85070.jpg
S3: http://media.fotoapparatuur.nl/IG/70573.jpg
ImageResizer OK: http://test.fotoapparatuur.nl:42424/s3/media.fotoapparatuur.nl/IG/70573.jpg

Comment: So we have an expires date of `Mon, 28 Apr 2025 21:50:04 G4T` Were these uploaded with different tools, or on operating systems with different default languages? I've never seen "G4T" before.

Comment: The G4T is the result of an old bug in my code which added the images to S3. Apparently adding an image to S3 with an invalid expiry date is not a problem. This went undetected until now as these images always displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing blobs have an invalid Expires header set. `Mon, 28 Apr 2025 21:50:04 G4T` does not conform to the RFC for datetime values in HTTP headers, and AWSSDK correctly throws an exception when it encounters the malformed date.

The bad metadata should be replaced or removed from the failing blobs.